# Trying to add social buttons/ issues with instructions from "developers.facebook.com"

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am building my first website ever, and I would like to add a couple of social buttons (facebook, twitter, etc.)

Now facebook has this great page/service, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button#configurator that gives you detailed instructions on how to embed a variety of buttons on your website.

It also has the following detailed code for every button that might interests you (lets say the share button).

Problem is, the code does not work. I literally copy/pasted the example on a test.html file, I opened it to see the form of the button.. and nothing.

I even have experimented with heights, widths and background colors of the divs that suppose to carry the buttons but no button appears on the browser (latest mozilla).

Why this code doesnt work? It has all the tags, everything seems so detailed, and makes sense. I mean I wouldnt expect the button to be functional since I am not re-directing to any existing domain, but a button should appear right?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your Website Title</title>
    <!-- You can use Open Graph tags to customize link previews.
    Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
    <meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
    <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
    <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
    <meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <!-- Your share button code -->
    <div style="height:100px; width:180px; background-color: black;" class="fb-share-button" 
        data-href="http://www.youtube.com" 
        data-layout="button_count">
    </div>
    <p>I even typed a paragraph to make sure that the html document is rightly configured..</p>

    <script 
    src="https://www.facebook.com/assets.php/en_US/sdk.js" async></script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="{your-link-url}"></div

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try copying the script from the configurator again. I just went to the link you posted and copied their code into my project and it worked. Then I swapped in your share button code - and that still worked. Then, I swapped in your script tag and it stopped working. Something must be missing there.

Comment: Are you opening your test file via HTTP(S) in the browser? It can’t work if you just view it over the local file system, because then the protocol-relative URL used to embed the SDK can’t be properly resolved. (You can get that to work though, if you put the protocol in front of the SDK URL, `js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1";`)

Comment: @CBroe what you are saying makes sense. Can you be a bit more specific on what do you mean when you say put the protocol in front of the sdk url? (what do you mean by protocol here?) Sorry, remember first website..

Comment: Compare the line starting with `js.src =` in your sample code, with the line I posted …

Comment: @CBroe thank you for your comments, nothing has worked however.

Comment: Are you testing this via `http://` or not? And is the URL you are pointing the like button to publicly available?